# Pandas: Dataframe diff() with reset of value accounted for

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get delta between next values in dataframe, data supposed to by monotonically increasing but it's sometimes being resetted. And to account for that if value of diff is negative I want to not change it:

let's say I've got dataframe like:

```
val:
1
2
3
1
2
4
```

then after diff().fillna(0) operation I've got

```
val:
0
1
1
-2
1
2
```

But I would like to:

```
val:
0
1
1
1
1
2
```

Any easy way of doing it?

Comment: `I want to not change it` - you havent told us what you want to fill it with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), then use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to replace those negatives with the previous values:

```
d = df.name.diff()
d.where(d.gt(0), df.name.ffill())

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
Name: name, dtype: float64
```